# Is there a way to format the output format in .NET Core logging?

Tags: c#, logging, console-application, .net-core

I'm using the built in logging provider for logging into the console  (`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`) in a .NET Core console application.

Each logging entry produces two lines in the output. I would like to have each entry in one single line.
Is there a way to customize the output format?

Here is an example how I use it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
      .AddLogging() // This adds the Microsoft logging.
      .AddSingleton<IProjectGeneratorService, CSharpProjectGeneratorService>()
      .BuildServiceProvider();

    // Configure the console logging.
    serviceProvider
      .GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
      .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
    
    // Write a logging entry
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Program>();
    logger.LogDebug("Application started...");
}
```

What I get is:

```
dbug: Generator.Program[0]
      Application started...
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
dbug: Generator.Program[0]: Application started...
```

Any idea? I know, I could write a custom logger, but I would like to know if there is an other way.

Comment: It has been almost 3 years since the last activity on this question. Did Miscrosoft incorporate a feature like this in .Net Core 3?

Comment: Please use new built-in formatters, I've updated my answer with the details for .NET 5+ https://stackoverflow.com/a/44231390/5112433

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update:** Since .NET 5 this can be customized as shown by other answers: [Console log formatter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999)

Original Answer:

At the moment, this not configurable. The source code [is here on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b4439ca1fd994c8ec2592fb9614a841853ae08fb/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLogger.cs#L113-L117):

> ```
> logBuilder.Append(logName);
> logBuilder.Append("[");
> logBuilder.Append(eventId);
> logBuilder.AppendLine("]");
> ```

If you want that, you need to write your own logger. However you can just copy the source code of the console logger, modify as needed and change the namespaces so it doesn't interfere with the version Microsoft ships.

You can also open an [issue on the logging repo](https://github.com/dotnet/Extensions/issues) to ask for this option.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be the only way. Thanks for the links and the code snippet. This saved me time searching by myself :-)

Comment: updated to reflect changes and this question still receives a good amount of views

Answer (score 28):

For .NET 5+ use built-in [Simple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999#simple) console log formatter. It provides several customization options, for example:

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(logging =>
    logging.AddSimpleConsole(options =>
    {
        options.SingleLine = true;
        options.TimestampFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ";
    })
);
```

Leads to the output:

```
2023-04-13 21:43:47 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14] Now listening on: http://localhost:5190
```

If built-in customization is not enough, you can implement a [custom formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999#implement-a-custom-formatter).

P.S. In 2023 I rewrote this answer from scratch. Since 2017, .NET logging had been re-designed several times, and my old examples written back in .NET Core 2 do not serve any purpose anymore.

Comment: The formatter does not include the exception details you would need to log those separately

Comment: Do longer correct. Downvoted

Comment: @David I've updated the answer.  Time goes fast...

Answer (score 12):

This is updated in .NET 5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter. Now provides simple, systemd and json

Comment: I'm not sure if the original question was about a custom logging format, or just something without line breaks. Systemd and JSON options work well for many log aggregators that treat every line break as a separate log entry, like AWS CloudWatch.

Answer (score 8):

Although you can't specify your own custom format, it does support an alternative "systemd" format which you can select like this:

```cs
logging.AddConsole(options => {
  options.Format=ConsoleLoggerFormat.Systemd;
});
```

This outputs each log entry on one line **even if your text has newlines in it** (so exceptions aren't very pretty). It also doesn't use colors, which is an advantage if you're redirecting to a file.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from .NET 5 you can configure logging formatters to write each log entry in a single line. Use **SingleLine** property of Formatter to configure it

For example, you can configure console formatter in your `appsettings.json` without writing any additional code:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "FormatterName": "simple",
      "FormatterOptions": {
        "SingleLine": true,
        "TimestampFormat": "HH:mm:ss "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information in Microsoft Docs:

- SimpleConsoleFormatterOptions [class definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.simpleconsoleformatteroptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)
- Console log formatting in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#set-formatter-with-configuration)

Answer (score 7):

This is now easy to do with [SimpleConsoleFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#simple) from the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging.console) package.

The source code of SimpleConsoleFormatter is [here on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/01b7e73cd378145264a7cb7a09365b41ed42b240/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/SimpleConsoleFormatter.cs#L66).

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
                .AddSimpleConsole(formatterOptions =>
                {
                    formatterOptions.SingleLine = true;
                })
                .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug))
            .BuildServiceProvider();

      // Write a logging entry
      var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
      logger.LogDebug("Application started...");
}
```

Output:

```
dbug: Generator.Program[0]: Application started...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a logging library like Serilog.

Using the instructions from the [ASP.NET Core integration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) you can later simply provide a logging output template via the [Console sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console)

```
.WriteTo.Console(
    outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
```