# How to remove `class name/ILoggerFactory` part?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I'm creating a C# 6 console program. The following code print `Program[0]` (ILoggerFactory/class name? What's `[0]`?) in every line. I'm create a small test/debug program which doesn't need it. How to remove this part?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using ILoggerFactory loggerFactory =
    LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        builder.AddSimpleConsole(options =>
        {
            options.IncludeScopes = true;
            options.SingleLine = true;
            options.TimestampFormat = "HH:mm:ss ";
        }));

ILogger<Program> logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

logger.LogInformation("Hello World!");
logger.LogInformation("Logs contain timestamp and log level.");
logger.LogInformation("Each log message is fit in a single line.");
```

Output:

```
10:01:30 info: Program[0] Hello World!
10:01:30 info: Program[0] Logs contain timestamp and log level.
10:01:30 info: Program[0] Each log message is fit in a single line.
```

Need to remove these `Program[0]`.

Comment: do you really need use ILoggerFactory? Why don't you use Console.WriteLine?

Comment: i want to print the time in front of every line. Also, i may need to actually log the output to a file or others. Or utilize other feature of logging framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to format the output format in .NET Core logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230373/is-there-a-way-to-format-the-output-format-in-net-core-logging)

Comment: Not really. I read the link in the most popular answer. It has a way complex way to solve the problem. (Not `AddSimpleConsole`)

Comment: oh, ok! sorry then!

Comment: What are your requirements? `AddSimpleConsole` provides a simple approach, but it's not highly configurable. Adding a custom logger is highly configurable, but more complex. Using a more powerful library like Serilog is simple, but adds a NuGet dependency. How much are you willing to do to get the customization you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console logging provided by Microsoft only has a few simple configuration options, as you've discovered. To get more custom formatting, it requires you to write your own custom console logger.

If you're willing to use another, more full-featured logging framework behind the scenes, you can still use Microsoft's abstraction layer while getting more configurability. For example, if you include the `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` and `Serilog.Sinks.Console` packages, you can change your code to something like this:

```
Serilog.ILogger serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console(
            outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u4}: {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        )
        .CreateLogger();
Serilog.Log.Logger = serilogLogger; // if you want to use Serilog directly
using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder.AddSerilog(serilogLogger);
});

ILogger<UserQuery> logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<UserQuery>();

logger.LogInformation("Hello World!");
logger.LogInformation(new Exception("foo"), "Logs contain timestamp and log level.");
logger.LogInformation("Each log message is fit in a single line.");
```

Output:

> 23:00:29 INFO: Hello World!
> 23:00:29 INFO: Logs contain timestamp and log level.
> System.Exception: foo
> 23:00:29 INFO: Each log message is fit in a single line.

Comment: I will use Serilog since it's one of the most popular logging frameworks. However, `LoggerFactory.Create(...)` got the error of `'LoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'Create'`

Comment: It probably needs nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. How to compare using `Serilog.Log.Logger` directly with creating a `ILogger<UserQuery> logger`?

Comment: I have a question on log SignalR trace logs to file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75839822/serilog-how-to-write-trace-logs-of-signalr-into-log-file Do you know if it's possible? Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you need the two packages I mentioned. Using Microsoft's interfaces just makes it easier if you want to switch logging frameworks in the future.

Comment: (`UserQuery` was just a copy-paste error on my part, since I was testing in LINQPad. You'll want to use `ILogger<Program>` or whatever other class you're logging for.)

Answer (score -1):

Please check the output template configuration for logging.

Adjusting the output template to show only message will make it work to remove the application/class name in your case

Example template only not modified to give what you are expecting.

.WriteTo.File("log.txt",
outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")

Comment: .WriteTo.File is a serilog configuration.