# Serilog how to write trace logs of SignalR into log file?

Tags: c#, signalr, serilog

I have the following code to enable logging trace logs of SignalR calls. However, the code doesn't work?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SeriLog;

var seriLoglogger = new LoggerConfiguration() // SeriLog.Core.Logger?
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File(...)
    .CreateLogger();
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => Builder.AddSerilog(seriLogLogger));
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("...");

logger.LogInformation("This works"); // This line works

var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(...)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddSerilog(seriLoglogger);
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);

    }
```

I can see the trace logs on screen if I add the following lines in `.ConfigureLogging(logging => { .... }`.

```
logging.AddSystemdConsole(o => { ... });
```

or
logging.AddConsole();

However, it doesn't have `logging.AddFile()`?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0#azure-app-service

Answer (score -1):

Even though you've got `HubConnectionBuilder`'s logging set to emit at a Trace level, the Serilog logger you're using isn't, as you can see by adding this line:

```
logger.LogTrace("This doesn't work");
```

Serilog's version of "Trace" is "Verbose", which you can set here:

```
var seriLoglogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose() // Emit "Trace"-level logs.
    .WriteTo.Console()
    ...
```